# Windows Mobile problems with ReceiveBufferSize

Tags: c#, sockets, windows-mobile, compact-framework

So I have a bit of a pickle, I have this code running on desktop .net 4.5 but it will not compile in .NET 3.5 for Windows CE/ Windows Mobile 6.1 Pro...

```
public void Init()
        {
            try
            {
                myTcpListener = new TcpListener(myAddress, myPortNumber);
                myTcpListener.Server.RecieveBufferSize = 500000;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Also tried to use `TcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 500000;` but this will raise an exception.

> An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a
>   getsockopt or setsockopt call

I am a bit unsure how to proceed... the purpose was to have a buffer large enough to hold 500.000 bytes... perhaps I need to handle this in a different manner.

EDIT: Here is the source code

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SmartDevice_Server
{
    /// <summary>
    /// ClientConnection saves connection information is used to keep context in Async and Event calls
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="networkStream"> NetworkStream Object of TCPClient</param>
    /// <param name="data">Byte array that serves as Buffer</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public class ClientConnection : EventArgs
    {
        public NetworkStream NetworkStream { get; private set; }
        public byte[] Data { get; private set; }
        public int byteReadCount { get; set; }

        public ClientConnection(NetworkStream networkStream, byte[] data)
        {
            NetworkStream = networkStream;
            Data = data;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// MySocket - Is a server that listens for events and triggers Events upon Request Completion 
    /// </summary>
    public class MySocketTCP
    {
        #region Members
        TcpListener myTcpListener;
        TcpClient myTcpClient;
        NetworkStream myNetworkStream;

        const string localHost = "127.0.0.1";
        IPAddress myAddress = IPAddress.Parse(localHost);
        int myPortNumber = 58889;
        byte[] myData;

        int bytesReadCount;
        const int MIN_REQUEST_STRING_SIZE = 10;

        int TimeStart;

        //Event Setup
        public event socketReadCompleteHandler socketReadCompleteEvent;
        public EventArgs eventArguments = null;
        public delegate void socketReadCompleteHandler(MySocketTCP myTcpSocket, ClientConnection eventArguments);

        //BufferSize
        public const int myBufferSize = 300000;

        #endregion

        //Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// MySocketTCP Constructor
        /// NOTE: By default connects to local host (127.0.0.1:58889)
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public MySocketTCP()
        {
            Init();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor overloaded to receive IPAdress Host, and Port number
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hostAddress">IPAdress that represent an IP address</param>
        /// <param name="portNumber">Integer that represents the port number</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public MySocketTCP(IPAddress hostAddress, int portNumber)
        {
            myAddress = hostAddress;
            myPortNumber = portNumber;

            Init();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the TCPListner with address, and port number
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void Init()
        {
            try
            {
                myTcpListener = new TcpListener(myAddress, myPortNumber);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Listens Asynchronously to Clients, class a recieveMessageHandler to process the read
        /// 
        /// * TODO_Listener_Timer: After you accept a connection you wait for data to be Read indefinitely
        /// Possible solution: Use a timeout to close the socket connection.
        /// Check WIKI, TODOS
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void ListenAsync()
        {
            myTcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                myTcpClient = myTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                //myTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize = 300000;


                var client = new ClientConnection(myTcpClient.GetStream(), new byte[myTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize]);

                // Capture the specific client and pass it to the receive handler
                client.NetworkStream.BeginRead(client.Data, 0, client.Data.Length, r => receiveMessageHandler(r, client), null);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Callback is used to read the request Asynchronously, triggers socketReadCompleteEvent
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="asyncResult"></param>
        /// <param name="clientInstance"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void receiveMessageHandler(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ClientConnection clientInstance)
        {
            bytesReadCount = 0;

            lock (clientInstance.NetworkStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    bytesReadCount = clientInstance.NetworkStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
                    clientInstance.byteReadCount = bytesReadCount;
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ioexcp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ioexcp.ToString());
                }
                catch (System.ObjectDisposedException objdispexc)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(objdispexc.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception excp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
                }
            }

            if (bytesReadCount < MIN_REQUEST_STRING_SIZE)
            {
                //Could not read form client.
                Debug.WriteLine("NO DATA READ. Close Connection");
                //If there is no data then close connection.

                //clientInstance.NetworkStream.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                if (socketReadCompleteEvent != null)
                {
                    socketReadCompleteEvent(this, clientInstance);
                }
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Reads the request, uses the ClientConnection for context
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connObj">Connection object contains the NetworkStream,
        /// Data Buffer, and Number of bytes read.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public string ReadAsync(ClientConnection connObj)
        {
            int bytesReadCount = connObj.byteReadCount;
            byte[] myData = connObj.Data;

            string xmlMessage;

            try
            {
                xmlMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myData, 0, bytesReadCount);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            return xmlMessage;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Is used to send/write the message to the correct socket
        /// Closes the connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connObj">context object</param>
        /// <param name="outMessage">message to send</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void WriteAsync(ClientConnection connObj, string outMessage)
        {
            const int timeDivisor = 10000;
            byte[] outBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(outMessage);

            try
            {
                Delay(outBytes.Length/timeDivisor);
                connObj.NetworkStream.Write(outBytes, 0, outBytes.Length);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

            //TODO_5254: Closes the connection, check MoSync side.
            //try
            //{
            //    connObj.NetworkStream.Close();
            //}
            //catch (Exception ex)
            //{
            //    throw ex;
            //}

            int TimeEnd = Environment.TickCount;
            int TimeResult = TimeEnd - TimeStart;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes TCPClient
        /// Warning: Does not close the underlying connection.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public void Close()
        {
            try
            {

                myTcpClient.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {       
                throw ex;
            }
        }

       /// <summary>
       /// Helper Function creates timeouts and delays.
       /// </summary>
       /// <param name="ms"></param>
       /// <returns></returns>
       private void Delay(int ms)
       {
           int time = Environment.TickCount;

           do
           {
               if (Environment.TickCount - time >= ms) return;
           } while (true);
       }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
try
                {
                    bytesReadCount = clientInstance.NetworkStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
                    clientInstance.stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientInstance.Data, 0, bytesReadCount));
                    //If buffer is bigger than myTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize
                    while (clientInstance.NetworkStream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("More data to read...");
                        //clientInstance.NetworkStream.EndRead(asyncResult);
                        int chuckByteSize = clientInstance.NetworkStream.Read(clientInstance.Data, 0, myTcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                        bytesReadCount += chuckByteSize;
                        //string textReceived = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientInstance.Data, 0, chuckByteSize);
                        clientInstance.stringBuilder.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientInstance.Data, 0, chuckByteSize));
                        //BP - Ver Data
                    }
                    clientInstance.byteReadCount = bytesReadCount;
                    //string sbString = clientInstance.sb.ToString();
                    //int sizeString = sbString.Length;
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException ioexcp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(ioexcp.ToString());
                }
                catch (System.ObjectDisposedException objdispexc)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(objdispexc.ToString());
                }
                catch (Exception excp)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine(excp.ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: I thought the `TcpListener.Server.RecieveBufferSize` was determined by the network - not something that gets set to whatever sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear based on your question, do you mean 50,000 or 500,000 (the code and text don't agree).

[The documentation indicates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916772.aspx) that `setsockopt` with `SOL_SOCKET` and `SO_RCVBUF` should be valid in the OS, though it's possible that the platform you're on doesn't allow it.

That said, I've transferred much larger amounts of data than 50k (and even 500k) over a socket without problem and I've never set this property.  Is there a specific reason you're using it?  If you omit it, I would expect calls using the socket to still work.

Comment: I want to transfer 500.000 bytes over a socket connection, localhost. I have a C++ client sending the data, and I only receive 32768 and can only send ~16k. I think I may need to create a bufferManager, but I also need to dispose of the object properly since my thread is being closed and an exception is being thrown from time to time:
The thread 0xe612268a has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.dll

If I set this on desktop version I can send that amount of data.

Comment: My bet is that `bytesReadCount` !=  `client.Data.Length`.  You can't assume you're going to get all of the data in one pass, you need to keep receiving until you've hit the expected length (your receive callback should call receive again)

Comment: The problem on my side is that there can be multiple requests being done at the same time... So How do i Control the requests being done? That is I don't know ahead of time the size of the requests that are being done.

Comment: Pass the length in as the state object to the callback.

Comment: I tried
while (true)
            {
                myTcpClient = myTcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                int myBufferSize = 500000;

                ClientConnection client = new ClientConnection(myTcpClient.GetStream(), new byte[myBufferSize]);

                // Capture the specific client and pass it to the receive handler
                client.NetworkStream.BeginRead(client.Data, 0, myBufferSize, r => receiveMessageHandler(r, client), null);
            }
This will only read 32767 in EndRead. Can you provide me with a sample of a server for WinMobile? googled but can't find any

Comment: I have updated my code I know read it chunk by chunk... it's working but still feels unsatisfactory in terms of cleanliness of the code, i think there is something that I am missing.

Comment: Your code update looks much better, and right, to me.  The only thing that might be different would be to check and see if the client stream `Size` itself is available (though it might now be, so checking `DataAvailable` is probably fine as well).  You are going to want to verify the connection is still live in that while loop, in case the client disconnects while sending data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, that connection check is a good point.